# How to run Jenkins as administrator on my local machine?

Tags: jenkins

> can anyone help me how to run Jenkins as an administrator? I have
>   tried my best but couldn't find any solution. Please help

Comment: Could you provide us the info about in which environment you are trying to establish Jenkins.

Comment: Hi Suresh, I am running on windows (locally) as war file. Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Open the command prompt by selecting "Run as Administrator" and run the war file.

Comment: Hi, thanks I am able to run it as Administrator but the work behind it is not achieved. Actually, jenkins shuts down itself after running each build and I have to restart it again and again so that if I run it as administrator then would fix it but it doesn't, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

if your jenkins running by window service, try this:

1. open services and find jenkins
2. right click -> Properties
3. go to 'Log on' Tap
4. Check 'This account'
5. typing your account that has permission of admin
6. restart jenkins

I wish you well.

Comment: or not.. how about this? https://coderwall.com/p/-avxmq/start-jenkins-as-administrator